# Wordpress shortcodes only working in posts, not pages. Custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a theme for a friend but some some reason I can't get shortcodes to work in Pages. They only work in Posts.

My page.php file is very simple at the moment:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        echo '<div class="hero-unit"><div class="container"><h1>'.get_the_title().'</h1></div></div>';
        echo '<div class="container clearfix" id="main-content">'.get_the_content().'</div>';
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is working fine but is just displaying the shortcode as text.
IE I am trying to use the shortcode [wp_sitemap_page] the page just renders '[wp_sitemap_page]' in text.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your post content is displayed via `echo get_the_content()` which is a function that returns the content WITHOUT applying the default filters (`wpautop`, `do_shortcode` etc) that are applied normally when you use `the_content()` instead.

This should fix it:

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="hero-unit"><div class="container"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></div></div>
        <div class="container clearfix" id="main-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    <?php endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: @user1636130 Mark as the solution when you get a chance!  I also just updated it with the fixed code that uses `the_title()` and `the_content()` rather than `get_the_title()` and `get_the_content()`.

Comment: Thanks for your time :) I will mark it as soon as I'm allowed.

Comment: You could also do `$content = get_the_content(); echo apply_filters('the_content', $content);` which will pass the unfiltered content returned by `get_the_content()` through the default filter used on `the_content()`.